# How can I Set the Input value Using Javascript not just for view but permanent value in element when I inspect element?

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

As question says it all.

And Please don't rate it as bad because I will not be able to ask any question in future if you think it is not a good question then just let me know in comments And I will try to improve.

What I'm trying to do is when I type something in text input it I am setting its value from suggestion and adding the value in text input from suggestion you can say appending the value.

let us suppose we have xxxx value already stored and it shows me in when I inspect element. but when I add new value in input using javascript and I inspect element it remains xxxx so it is not appending in element so I am unable to add more values after comma because it just getting the stored value xxxx when I try to append.

Hope getting my point. 
Thanks

here is the code it might help you to help me.

```
en4.core.runonce.add(function (){
    var contentAutocomplete = new Autocompleter.Request.JSON('1_1_17', '<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'edit', 'action' => 'getinterest' ), 'default', true) ?>', {
        'postVar' : 'text',
        'minLength': 1,
        'selectMode': 'pick',
        'autocompleteType': 'tag',
        'className': 'seaocore-autosuggest tag-autosuggest',
        'customChoices' : true,
        'filterSubset' : true,
        'multiple' : false,
        'injectChoice': function(token){
            var choice = new Element('li', {'class': 'autocompleter-choices', 'id':token.label});
            new Element('div', {'html': this.markQueryValue(token.label),'class': 'autocompleter-choice'}).inject(choice);
            this.addChoiceEvents(choice).inject(this.choices);
            choice.store('autocompleteChoice', token);
        },
    });

    var test = document.getElementById('1_1_17').value;
    contentAutocomplete.addEvent('onSelection', function(input) {
        document.getElementById('1_1_17').value = test+','+input;
    });
});
```

I am using mootools.

Comment: What you're seeing in the console is the attribute, what you're changing is the property, which is why it doesn't update in the console, but it shouldn't have to, you should be using the property, so it shouldn't update in the console. If it's not working you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: If you want to change the value permanently, then you need to store the data somewhere persistent (usually the server). Modifying the element in the DOM (whether or not you use a technique that makes it show up in the attribute) will never do that.

Comment: I added the code can you please review it so if there is something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the solution here is the solution of my answer if anyone in need I am sharing.

```
contentAutocomplete.addEvent('onSelection', function (input) {
    var inputEl = document.getElementById('1_1_17'); //input element which we are populating via suggestions
    var get = inputEl.getAttribute("value"); //get attribute value 
    var set = inputEl.setAttribute("value", get + "," + input); // set the attribute to store value in permanent way it will not mess up with next suggestion we add
    var get_again = inputEl.getAttribute("value"); // Get the attribute again for setting value for view
    inputEl.value = get_again; // setting the value for view
});
```

Comment: Great (`+1`) please add also some text commenting the changes.

Comment: And btw what is `element` in the function arguments? is it the input element?

Comment: @Sergio Yes I added the commenting and sorry the parameter was only input which we select from suggestion.

Comment: @Sergio do you know why when I select value by pressing Enter it adds multiple values into the field? Selecting with mouse click works fine but selecting the value with enter key adds the one value multiple times probably adds 3 to 4 values to input.

Comment: Hmm have to read the problem again. If you can make a fiddle with the problem I can take a look at it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o9pb1upd/14/ I just created this but we cant access the url from where I am getting the suggestion because of same origin policy.

Comment: install this on chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en and then use this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/o9pb1upd/21/ hope this will help